# Creating A Query From SQL Where Condition

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to create a a query based on the Where condition from the previous statement in the same form, but the query is not being created when i run the button.

Something like this:

```
Dim qdf As QueryDef

strSql = "SELECT * FROM qryEvents WHERE strWhere"

'Delete the query if it already exists
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "qryEvents_Search"

Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("qryEvents_Search", strWhere)
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryEvents_Search"

'release memory
qdf.Close
Set qdf = Nothing
```

The Where condition part is:

```
If Len(strWhere) > 0 Then
If Nz(DCount("*", "qryEvents", Left(strWhere, Len(strWhere) - 0)), 0) > 0 Then
strWhere = "WHERE " & Left(strWhere, Len(strWhere) - 0)
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qryEvents " & strWhere & ";"
```

Comment: Please share the code as you're using it. In the top part, you're constructing `strSql`, but then passing only `strWhere` to the `CreateQueryDef`, and are making some more errors, and the bottom part is even more unclear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A WHERE clause doesn't make a query. You need the SELECT part too.

e.g.

```
strNewSql = "SELECT * FROM otherEvents " & strWhere
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("qryEvents_Search", strNewSql)
```